# Inventory reconstruction in Excel from list of unique product inventory states and timestamps

Tags: excel, datetime, count, formula, uniqueidentifier

```
id  status      date      time

a   received    01-Jan-14 04:00
a   available   05-Jan-14 05:00
a   returned    06-Jan-14 13:00
a   destroyed   07-Jan-14 12:00
b   received    10-Jan-14 14:00
b   available   11-Jan-14 08:00
b   returned    12-Jan-14 09:00
b   destroyed   13-Jan-14 07:00
c   received    02-Jan-14 05:00
c   available   03-Jan-14 07:00
c   returned    05-Jan-14 08:00
d   received    09-Jan-14 02:00
d   available   12-Jan-14 06:00
(etc)
```

I have unique `id`s, each with a `status`, a `date` and a `time`.  For a given date/time, I need to count the `available` ones.  For a given date/time, I need to count the `received` ones.  I intend to input a date and time in a given cell and do those counts based on that date and time.

i.e. `January 3, 2014 06:00`, there are `2` `received` and `0` `available` widgets [`a` is received, not available yet; `c` received but not available yet].

How do I do this as an Excel formula?

Comment: Welcome. What have you tried so far (see [ask] to improve the content of your post).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `01=Jan-14` is in date format and in C2, F1 contains `January 3, 2014 06:00` in date format, `available` is always paired with `received` and immediately follows that, and you have concatenated in E2 and copied down:

```
=C2+D2
```

Then for `available` please try:

```
=COUNTIFS(B2:B100,"received",E2:E100,"<"&F1,B3:B101,"available",E3:E101,"<"&F1)
```

and for `received`:

```
=COUNTIFS(B:B,"received",E:E,"<"&F1)
```

with the range for the former extended beyond Rows100/101 to suit.